# maximum number of nested transaction and nested try-catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

how many number of nested transaction and nested try catch sql can have in one single session.

Answer (score 0):

Appears it's 375. The below works:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 375 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + REPLICATE('    ',T.I) + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'BEGIN TRY') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + REPLICATE('    ',T.I+1 )+  N'SELECT 1;'
                     FROM Tally T
                     ORDER BY T.I
                     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
              STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +REPLICATE('    ',T.I) + N'END TRY' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + REPLICATE('    ',T.I) + CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'BEGIN CATCH')+ NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +  + REPLICATE('    ',T.I+1) + N'SELECT 2;' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +  + REPLICATE('    ',T.I) + N'END CATCH' 
                     FROM Tally T
                     ORDER BY T.I DESC
                     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'')

--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If, however, you change it to `TOP 376` you get the error:

> Msg 191, Level 15, State 1, Line 755 
>   Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.